# Forcing authentication on Maven release

Tags: maven, deployment, nexus, bad-request, unauthorized

I have a problem getting Maven to release to a Nexus server. Seemingly, it refuses to use my provided username and password (but there might be other problems as well).

When I first type 'mvn release:perform', I get a'not authorized'-error. However, some files are created on the Nexus, namely a pom with checksums etc. When I try a second time (without changing anything), I get a different error: '400 bad request'

When I delete the files and try again, I get the first error once again.

I have run this with the -X flag to see if I can make any sense of what is happening, and I have discovered that the first time I run the command, maven omits my username and password provided in settings.xml:

[INFO] [DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for http://nexus.example.com/content/repositories/releases

When I run it the second time, it includes my credentials:

[INFO] [DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for http://nexus.example.com/content/repositories/releases/ as developers

Notice it says 'as developers'

Of course I don't know that the fact that it prints it differently actually means anything, but it seems that way.

When I allow redeploy for the releases repository in Nexus, I always get the first variant (not authorized).

If anyone can tell me how I might force Maven to use my credentials (if that is indeed what it is not doing) or on what else might be wrong, I would be very happy.

Answer (score 2):

I have got it working now, by specifying in the maven release plugin that it only deploy, and not deploy and deploy site as is default.

mvn site:deploy fails with the error: Wagon protocol 'http' does not support directory copying.

Of course, my original error message did not refer very much to site at all.
Way to produce useful error messages, Maven!

I found a way to force preemptive authentication here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-http-settings.html (it didn't solve my problem, but it is an answer to the title.)